# Basic Js function to scale two DIV's heights

Tags: javascript

I want `#result` to being scaled to `#sidebar` height if set. If not, leaving `#result` at its original height.

My code:

```
window.onload = setDiv;

function setDiv() {
    var e = document.getElementById('sidebar'); // Get the sidebar infos
    var eh = e.offsetHeight // div height
    if ( typeof(eh) == "undefined" || typeof(eh) == null)  { // if sidebar isnt in the page
        alert(eh);
        return true;
    } else {
        var eh = e.offsetHeight // div height
        var d = document.getElementById('result') // Get the result div height
        var dh = d.offsetHeight // div height
        d.style.height = eh + 65 + 'px'; // Set result div height to sidebar height
        alert(d);
        document.write(dh);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I don't think HTML/CSS is needed.

Thank you.

Comment: What does the isset tag mean?

Comment: What does `isset()` have to do with this?

Comment: sorry, I tought the use of typeof(eh) == "undefined" || typeof(eh) == null could be considered as an isset()

Comment: @Duke - try to work on more consistently formatting your code, and even though it's not necessary, end each statement in a semicolon. It's a good practice to get into and is recommended by 9 out of 10 doctors.

Comment: Thanks, I take the advice :) By formatting you mean indentation ? I've had some trouble to make it look nice with the code function here ...

Comment: @Duke - Yes, indentation and spacing in the statement itself. I use four spaces (no `TAB` for me) and always space out any operators, variables and equal signs. I feel it makes it a lot easier to visually inspect for errors or problems. Also, if you're not using it, try Firebug or Chrome Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This causes an error because `e` does not exist (yet):

```
var e = document.getElementById('sidebar'); // <<< This is what doesn't work
```

This is because your `window.onload` is not done right. Take the parentheses off:

```
window.onload = setDiv;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/u8DZx/3/

I want to demonstrate how easy this is to do in a library like jQuery. `window.onload` does not always work the way you think either; it's often better to use `onDomReady`, or [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) in jQuery. You can also add multiple handlers at different points in the page load, which is more difficult just using the `window.onload` method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){setDiv();},2000); // So you can see the transition
});

function setDiv() {
    var $sidebar = $('#sidebar');
    if ($sidebar.size() === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $('#result').animate({
            height : $('#sidebar').height()
        }, 5000);
        return false;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/u8DZx/1/

If you don't want the effect, just do:

```
$('#result').height($('#sidebar').height());
```

And if you actually meant to use `offsetHeight`, which it doesn't sound like that's what you want (`height` instead), you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){setDiv();},2000); // So you can see the transition
});

function setDiv() {
    var $sidebar = $('#sidebar');
    if ($sidebar.size() === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $('#result').offset($('#sidebar').offset());
        return false;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/u8DZx/2/

Comment: Thank you a lot Jared, your answer is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

This line seems wrong:

```
if ( typeof(eh) == "undefined" || "null") { // if sidebar isnt in the page
```

try this:

```
if ( typeof(eh) == "undefined" || typeof(eh) == null) { // if sidebar isnt in the page
```

---

Also, I would add in a try catch block.  If there is a throw you won't even know your code did not execute.

Comment: @Jared - that would work too.. I was trying to show the logic error he made and change as little as possible to be correct.  For example I would use `===` not `==` but I did not think that was worth making the answer more confusing.

Comment: Well, that's a good first step, but i'm getting the floowing error just one line before :  Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null

Comment: @Duke - Personally, I would do this type of thing using jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/style-properties/

Comment: @Jared - Thank you, I'm making my first steps in Jquery and didn't know it could carry about css so easily. I'll go deeper into it and post the solution before closing the topic.